# Can't delete Cloudant service - Error 400

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant

I am taking the DWC001 Bluemix Intro course exercise 3b. After creating a node.js app and binding a new Cloudant database, then deleted my app from dashboard, checked delete for Cloudant, my Cloudant service remains and I cannot delete it.

This error from Dashboard & cmdline:

```
Service instance RLCCloudant: Service broker error:    
{"description"=>"Error 400 received from broker url   
https://cloudantbroker.ng.bluemix.net/v2/service_instances/40791045-620f-
4fda-b9d4-eabe50c4783c?plan_id=cloudant-shared&service_id=cloudant"}
```

Comment: Is this still a problem after trying it again? Do you have more details on the error?

Answer (score 4):

As you can see in the [Bluemix Status Page](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status) we are currently experiencing some issues provisioning and managing Cloudant service instances in Bluemix. Bluemix users attempting to provision/unprovision/bind/unbind Cloudant service instances may see errors during these operations.  The operations team has restored the service to allow provisioning, binding and unbinding. Issues may still be experienced when unprovisioning a service (as in your case). 
Please visit that status page to see when the issues are resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The service has been restored by Cloudant team as announced at https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status.
Now the deletion action is working as normal.

Answer (score 0):

"Service Broker Error" usually means that something went wrong communicating with the service side. Please send a request to delete the service to Bluemix Support.